# Sort by id and then by name is quicker than sort by name?

Tags: python, sorting

I am using quicksort algorithm to sort data. For some reason, when I sort by id (integer) and then by name (string), the calculation is faster than when I only sort by name (string) from the beginning.

Assuming the quicksort algorithm is correct (and i don't use any randomization or helper-algorithm to find a good pivot), the data and its order are always the same and the code does not contain any bugs, what could possibly be the reason for that?

Comment: I assume you can provide some timing data gathered with `timeit` to show the difference together with some reproducible code?

Comment: By "sort by id and the by name", do you a single sort with a complex criteria, or 2 successive sorts?  And can you provide an idea of what the data looks like?

Comment: The time difference is about 8 seconds. I use 2 successive sorts. I am editing the question now to add code and example of data

Comment: Edited. Maybe the first sort changes the order of my data in such a way that causes the second sort to finish quicker? If this is true, I wonder why this is always happening

Comment: Please provide some actual code

Comment: @DeepSpace check the question now. i changed names of variables so there might be a few errors, but you can get the concept

Comment: Although the question doesn't make it clear what the relationship between id's and names is, but I'm wondering if the names have sufficient ordering to increase the time for quick sort, and if the id's are random enough to decrease the time for quick sort by id, and after the quick sort by id, the names are now random enough to decrease the time for sort by name. You could put in a static compare count to get an idea of what happens in the two cases.